# Extract data between epoch times in a csv using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I'm trying to work on the following sample data:

```
Amanda,1.00,1418691511,Non-Technical,v1
Charles,7.05,1417093994,Technical,v1
Christopher,7.00,1417102400,Technical,v2
David,4.00,1417093447,Non-Technical,v1
John,4.75,1417059582,Technical,v1
John,7.80,1417102602,Technical,v2
Joseph,7.80,1417093804,Technical,v1
Joseph,5.00,1423504662,Technical,v2
Michael,7.55,1417092924,Technical,v1
Richard,5.00,1417093649,Non-Technical,v1
Robert,3.00,1417092640,Non-Technical,v1
Thomas,6.75,1417102170,Technical,v1
William,4.50,1417093255,Non-Technical,v1
rd,2.00,1426017161,Technical,v8
rd,2.75,1426449217,Technical,v9
```

Here the third column in csv is the epoch date format timestamp of individual records.

I want to extract the data which has time stamp between today and past 3 days only.

Following is what I used to achieve it but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
awk -F , '{if ($3 >= system("date +%s --date="3 days ago"") && $3 <= system("date +%s")) { print }}'
```

Can you help me in understanding what went wrong here?

Comment: Edit your question to show your expected output. Also - do you mean 3 days or do you mean 3*24 hours? I mean if it's currently 4 pm on Friday and you have data timestamped 3pm on the Tuesday 3 days ago is that within the "3 days ago" window?

Answer (score 3):

The double quotes in this command do not work as you want them to:

```
awk -F , '{if ($3 >= system("date +%s --date="3 days ago"") && $3 <= system("date +%s")) { print }}'
                                             ^          ^
```

The two marked ones cause the trouble.

I'd probably use:

```
awk -F, -v old=$(date +%s --date="3 days ago") -v new=$(date +s) \
    '{ if ($3 >= old && $3 <= new) print }'
```

or even:

```
awk -F, -v old=$(date +%s --date="3 days ago") -v new=$(date +s) \
    '$3 >= old && $3 <= new'
```

There are times when `system` is necessary, but try to treat it as a 'bad smell'.  Usually, it is not actually necessary if you think carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The `system` command in awk prints the output to the screen, rather than returning a string. I would recommend passing two variables to awk instead:

```
awk -F, -vp="$(date +%s --date="3 days ago")" -vc="$(date +%s)" '$3 >= p && $3 <= c' file
```

It is completely unnecessary to use `if` in this case - awk's syntax is `condition { action }`, with the default action being `{print $0}` (or equivalently `{print}`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk, there's no need to use the `date` utility; gawk has a builtin `systime()` function:

```
awk -F , 'BEGIN { now = systime(); then = now - 259200 } $3 >= then && $3 <= now'
```

(259200 = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 is three days in seconds).